# String is posting as an integer in database

Tags: java, php, xml, database, android-volley

So I decided to build login and register activities for my application. The database and server are up and running and the application connects to it perfectly. The only issue that I am running into is that one of the fields that I am posting to the database is showing as an integer instead of a string as intended. The following are the java, xml, and php files that I am working with:

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://codeblue.net16.net/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String first_name, String last_name, String email, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("first_name", first_name);
        params.put("last_name", last_name);
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

}
```

**RegisterRequest.java**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.alex.codeblue.R;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText editFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFirstName);
        final EditText editLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLastName);
        final EditText editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        final EditText editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        final Button buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String first_name = editFirstName.getText().toString();
                final String last_name = editLastName.getText().toString();
                final String email = editEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = editPassword.getText().toString();

                Log.d("first_name", first_name);
                Log.d("last_name", last_name);
                Log.d("email", email);
                Log.d("password", password);

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //Log.d("JSON Parser", response);
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");


                            if (success) {
                                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                                CharSequence text = "Registration Successful";
                                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                                toast.show();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Registration Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                };

                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(first_name, last_name, email, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = new Volley().newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activit_register.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.alex.codeblue.LoginAndRegister.RegisterActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:id="@+id/editFirstName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="First Name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:id="@+id/editLastName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editFirstName"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Last Name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editLastName"
        android:hint="Email" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editPassword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Password" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPassword"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("mysql11.000webhost.com", "(number for 000webhost.com)_user", "(password)", "(number for 000webhost.com)_data");

    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $password);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;  
        $response["first_name"] = $first_name;
        $response["last_name"] = $last_name;
        $response["email"] = $email;
        $response["password"] = $password;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("mysql11.000webhost.com", "(number for 000webhost.com)_user", "(password)", "(number for 000webhost.com)_data");

    $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
    $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

        $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $first_name, $last_name, $email, $password);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

        $response = array();
        $response["success"] = true;  

        echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Now the issue that I am running into is that when the user inputs the "last_name" field as a string, in the database it will be entered as an integer and will show a 0. To test this theory I entered a number in the "last_name" field and that number showed up in the database. Every other field seems to be working as intended. I can't seem to find where the error is occuring. I have been searching for the past day and a half for the solution to this problem and I can't seem to find the error. Anyone have any ideas?

Per request, the following are pictures of the database:

[Database Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pODzZ.png)

[Output of Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7zbo.png)

Comment: What's the datatype of the column in your database?

Comment: ^ If it's an integer then you found your problem

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this. last_name is set up exactly the same as first_name. They are both varchars and first_name seems to come through fine. This is why I am so perplexed by this.

Comment: @AlexKiss Can you output or printthe values before you insert into database

Comment: @LearningPhase Great idea, I used Log.d to print all of the strings right before inserting them into the database. Refer to the updated RegisterActivity.java above to see how. The output is as follows: D/first_name: F
D/last_name: L
D/email: e
D/password: 123.  In the database the values are F, 0, e, and 123 respectively.

Comment: It means you are able to see the output you intend to put in the database , correct?

Comment: @LearningPhase Yes, the console prints the correct strings as the outputs right before posting them to the database. I will try and recreate the database as Blue Phoenix has suggested and I will report back with the results. Unfortunately, 000webhost.com is experiencing a bug that requires an hour or two before the database is created. I will report back as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is not in the code but in  your MySQL database schema. Please check your MySQL database columns data type. They should be varchar.

Since your database is OK and need to debug your code. I'd suggested you to check your php code by saving data in some file before inserting into database as following code.

Now I found the error in the php code. look detail of mysqli_stmt_bind_param at http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php for detail.

you should include "ssss" instead of "siss" i - means integer so the last name is expected as integer. you must change i to s - means string in arguments.

**Register.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql11.000webhost.com", "(number for 000webhost.com)_user", "(password)", "(number for 000webhost.com)_data");

$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];


    $myfile = fopen("checkdata.log", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, "\nfirst name= ".$first_name." last name= ".$last_name." email= ".$email." password=".$password." \n");       
    fclose($myfile);

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssss", $first_name, $last_name, $email, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this. last_name is set up exactly the same as first_name. They are both varchars and first_name seems to come through fine. This is why I am so perplexed by this.

Comment: oh, that is strange. it should be fine if the data type is varchar too.

Comment: How about creating new database and test it again ?

Comment: I will give that a try. I'm not entirely sure why considering I just updated the RegisterActivity.java code to print the strings to the console before passing them to the database and they seem to all come out fine. I posted the current database structure and output as it currently stands at the end of the post.

Comment: I think you should check the php file too. save some data in file before inserting into database.

Comment: here is my example to save some data in file in php                                                            $myfile = fopen("search3.log", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
     fwrite($myfile, "\ninputs cat_name=".$catalog." rating=".$rating." p1=".$p1." cursine=".$cui." \n");
     fwrite($myfile, "\nx0=".$x0." y0=".$y0." r=".$r. " \n");
     fclose($myfile);

Comment: how about testing php file in wamp server in local host?

Comment: Should I be pasting that just underneath $password = $_POST["password"]; and above $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, ... ALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");? If so, should i paste your code as is? Also I haven't attempted to test the php file in a wamp server yet.

Comment: please wait I will write a php file for you

Comment: Thank you very much. I really do appreciate the assistance.

Comment: please take a look at my edited answer with your modified php code. and check the log file after calling it.

Comment: There was a checkdata.log file that showed up in my database after I inserted the code as you asked. I'm assuming that this is what was intended. The input for first_name was First, last_name was Last, email was email, and password was 123. The checkdata.log file output the following:  first name= First last name= Last email= email password=123. This seems to indicate that the inputs match the outputs as intended.

Comment: wow, I found the error in your php code, change mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $first_name, $last_name, $email, $password); with mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssss", $first_name, $last_name, $email, $password);

Comment: now my updated php file should be  completed and error free. test it again and hope you find the soultion.